# Remove padding from video

Tags: html, css, video, youtube, resize

The vertical black that you see in the image that is to the left and right of the video shouldn’t be there.

The video should fill the whole screen inside its border when changed to different widths.

To reproduce issue, play the video then resize it to different widths.

https://jsfiddle.net/m3w6Lp70/

What would be adjusted in the css?

How do you get a YouTube video to fill the whole screen?

That is all I am trying to figure out how to do.

Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain-wrapper {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 670px;
  margin: auto;
}

.curtain-ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 58.208%;
}

.curtain {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: #333;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, gray, black), url("https://i.imgur.com/pwdit9N.png"), linear-gradient(to bottom right, #eee, #ccc);
  background-origin: padding-box, border-box, border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box, border-box;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px black inset, 0 -1px white, 0 -1px 0 1px #bbb, 0 2px 0 1px #aaa, 0 2px 10px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

<div class="outer">
  <div class="tcell">
    <div class="curtain-wrapper">
      <div class="curtain-ratio-keeper">
        <div class="curtain">

          <div class="wrap ">
            <div class="video video-frame"></div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you describe where the 58.208% comes from? I can't work it out given the youtube ratio of 16/9.

Comment: why not use the `<video>` tag that also allows the CSS use of `object-fit`?

Comment: 360 / 640 = 56.25% ///

15inch border
+30 +30 ///

390 / 670 = 58.2089%;

Comment: Can you show me how to use object-fit?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get object-fit to work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the border and the `padding-top` you have used around the `iframe`. The video is at 16:9 ratio I guess, which requires a `padding-top` of `56.25` but you have used `58.208` which compensates for the border you have used. Border appears inside the width of the element, so it affects the space available for the inner content(hence affecting the 16:9 ratio/`56.25%`). To fix you need to skip the border and use `box-shadow` instead and set `padding-top` to `56.25%`.

Comment: This is the math: 360 / 640 = 56.25% /// 15inch border +30 +30 /// 390 / 670 = 58.2089%

Comment: How would I do that, can you show me how to use box shadow instead?

Comment: I know the math and it wouldn't work when the page width is less that 390px. 

This gets tricky because you have used a gradient border and you can't use gradients in box-shadow and also there is this another issue with the round edges. It wont appear as you expect.  But good news..

Below code should work as you expect. Its your same code, just rearranged.
https://pastebin.com/a3Y1rwkR

Comment: The black horizontal line is still appearing, look. https://jsfiddle.net/qhs1xp98/ Click play and you will see it. Horizontal and vertical. See Image: https://i.imgur.com/8gyrTyJ.png

Comment: What else would need to be adjusted?

Comment: You have used max-width as 511px. Use a nice round number or one thats divisible by 4.